# Perl regular expression pattern matching the urls

Tags: regex, perl

I have an old perl code which I need to improvise it by debugging it in apache server but it has some regular expressions in it which I am not able to figure out exactly as I am new to perl. Could some one please explain what does the following code do?

```
my $target = " ";
$target = $1 if( $url =~ m|^$shorturl(\/.*)$|);
```

Here,
url is http://127.0.0.1/test.pl/content/dist/hale_bopp_2.mpg
shorturl is http://127.0.0.1/test.pl

Comment: What part of the regex are you unsure about? [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) (the official Perl regex tutorial) is a great resource for learning about regular expressions in Perl.

Answer (score 5):

Is extracts the "path info" component of the URL, the extra segments of the path after the path to the script.

```
http://127.0.0.1/test.pl/content/dist/hale_bopp_2.mpg
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(It should really be `$target = unescape_uri($1)` to handle escaped characters.)

Comment: So what does $1 here indicates exactly?

Comment: `$1` is the first capture group, so everything inside of the `(  )`. And that would be what ikegami highlighted here.

Comment: so, how can i get only the file name from the whole url? i.e., i want only hale_bopp_2.mpg string from url: http://127.0.0.1/test.pl/content/dist/hale_bopp_2.mpg

Comment: What you actually want is the last segment of the path in `$target`.

Answer (score -1):

From the language perspective, it matches $url with regexp enclosed in m| | and if it matches, put first capture (part of regex in parens) into $target.